# Discover tests when developing in remote container

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

I have done the following:

- cloned [pandas-dev/pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/)
- within vs code, I have installed the Remote Development extension pack
- I have opened this folder within a container, as instructed [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers)

But now, if I try to discover tests, it fails. Here is the output of `Python test log`:

```
python /root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.89148/pythonFiles/testing_tools/run_adapter.py discover pytest -- --rootdir /workspaces/pandas-dev -s --cache-clear pandas
Test Discovery failed: 
Error: /workspaces/pandas-dev/pandas/util/_test_decorators.py:97: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The 'warn' parameter of use() is deprecated since Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.  If any parameter follows 'warn', they should be pass as keyword, not positionally.
  mod.use("Agg", warn=True)
/workspaces/pandas-dev/pandas/util/_test_decorators.py:97: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The 'warn' parameter of use() is deprecated since Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.  If any parameter follows 'warn', they should be pass as keyword, not positionally.
  mod.use("Agg", warn=True)
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.7, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.8.2, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /workspaces/pandas-dev, inifile: setup.cfg, testpaths: pandas
plugins: forked-1.1.2, asyncio-0.12.0, cov-2.10.0, hypothesis-5.16.2, xdist-1.32.0
collected 0 items

============================ no tests ran in 0.01s =============================
ERROR: file not found: pandas


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.89148/pythonFiles/testing_tools/run_adapter.py", line 22, in <module>
    main(tool, cmd, subargs, toolargs)
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.89148/pythonFiles/testing_tools/adapter/__main__.py", line 100, in main
    parents, result = run(toolargs, **subargs)
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.89148/pythonFiles/testing_tools/adapter/pytest/_discovery.py", line 44, in discover
    raise Exception("pytest discovery failed (exit code {})".format(ec))
Exception: pytest discovery failed (exit code 4)
```

I am able to discover tests absolutely fine for the same repo when developing *outside* the container, i.e. with the dev environment built from source.

How can I discover tests when developing inside the container?

Comment: Can you show your settings in the container for running tests as well as the file layout in the workspace you opened in the container?

Comment: Hi @BrettCannon - looks like this was solved here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/34929